# Selecting just folder but seeing files too

Tags: c++, qt

I have:

```
QFileDialog file_dialog;
    file_dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);

    QStringList selected_directory; 
    selected_directory << file_dialog.getExistingDirectory();
```

But I cannot see any files. Is there any way to see them yet being able to select just directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory).

When you are calling the `getExistingDirectory` the `ShowDirsOnly` flag is set

```
 QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
                                                 "/home",
                                                 QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                 | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
```

Use instead the following:

```
QFileDialog dialog(this);
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
QStringList dirNames;
if (dialog.exec())
    dirNames = dialog.selectedFiles();
```

The selected directories can be retrieved from the `dirNames` string list.

Comment: @webcletic ok, thanks, the only minor problem with this is that the dialog is different to the one displayed by getExistingDirectory, is there a chance to make the first dialog do what I want?